# Javascript resetting an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm having with some very strange behaviour when I try to reset an array; eg:

```
data.length=0;
```

where data is an array. I'll try and include only the relevant code here but basically what I;m doing is on each iteration of my program I'm populating the array with updated values and the array then is used in another function. But when I reset the array the function appears to get the values on the first iteration but none afterwards.

However when I don't reset the array then the function gets the values, but also the older values. I don't want this, as I only want the new updated values only. This is a code snippet:

```
      var buffer = [['1',[0]],['2',[0]],['3',[0]],['4',[0]]];
      var dataset = [];

         ws.onmessage = function(evt){ 
         dataset.length=0;
         var distances = JSON.parse(evt.data);

         console.log(distances);

            for(var i=0; i<buffer.length; i++) {
                if(buffer[i][0] == distances.miles) {
                    buffer[i][1][0]++;
                    }
                //console.log(buffer);

                dataset.push(buffer[i][1][0]);
                draw();
                //console.log(dataset); 

            }

    }
```

The function uses the dataset array to redraw a chart.

I've tried to keep it simple here, but the full function is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2NXF2/58/).

I really don't know what's causing this unexpected behaviour.

EDIT:

console.log(dataset) shows the new updated values, but somehow dataset.length=0; is preventing the updated array to be used by the draw() function. As without the resetting of the array the array can be used by the draw() function.

EDIT:

I've tried to not reset the array but instead get the last 4 elements and put them in a new array and then send them to the draw(), but still the same odd behaviour:

```
            x = dataset.slice(-4);
            console.log(x);
            draw();
```

But if I don't do that or don't clear the array, then draw() render a 'wrong' chart. I can't see what is wrong.

THE problem somehow seems to reside with the resetting of the array and that because of this it means the draw() function appears to be called only once at the first iteration.

Please, Please help

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set `length` at all. To clear a list of all value, just set it to an empty list:

```
dataset = [];
```

Comment: This will break external references. That may not be important, but it's something to bear in mind.

Comment: `dataset = [];` or `dataset.length=0;` are nearly identic with the first one possibly creating a new array, thus allocating another space in the memory and the second one just resetting the existing array. To reset the array, setting the length is just fine or even better because of xophmeisters statement.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, I'm not sure, but why do you even have `dataset`?  You don't ever read anything out of it, and you say you want to clear it every time thru the array.

Do you mean do to something like:

```
for(var i=0; i<buffer.length; i++) {
    if(buffer[i][0] == distances.miles) {
        buffer[i][1][0]++;
    }
    dataset.push(buffer[i][1][0]);
}
draw(dataset); // draw outside the loop, using dataset.
```

Comment: Thansk if I do that, then nothing is drawn.

Comment: The `length` property is not read-only. Setting the length to zero is a valid way to empty an array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Comment: @hvgotcodes `array.length = 0;` will reset the array *without* breaking references. When you do `array = [];`, any references you had pointing to `array` will no longer work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but even if I have draw() outside the loop and reset by dataset=[] still nothing drawn. dataset array is used as an array in the actual draw() function.

Comment: @hvgotcodes if I don't reset the array then as the array gets bigger it draws all the elements. I only want the updated values it recieived.